# Cannot clone GitHub repository on EC2 Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm using EC2 Ubuntu virtual machine and try to clone private GitHub repository. But when I enter my username and password. I'm getting this error.

`remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.`

I also tried with GitHub generated token but didn't work.

The following solution doesn't work for me.

```
For Linux, you need to configure the local GIT client with a username and email address,

$ git config --global user.name "your_github_username"
$ git config --global user.email "your_github_email"
$ git config -l
Once GIT is configured, we can begin using it to access GitHub. Example:

$ git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
> Cloning into `YOUR-REPOSITORY`...
Username: <type your username>
Password: <type your password or personal access token (GitHub)
Now cache the given record in your computer to remembers the token:

$ git config --global credential.helper cache
If needed, anytime you can delete the cache record by:

$ git config --global --unset credential.helper
$ git config --system --unset credential.helper
Now try to pull with -v to verify

$ git pull -v
Linux/Debian (Clone as follows):

git clone https://<tokenhere>@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
```

It's really wired and I want some help with this issue.